# Batch script stopped working after working for over a month

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The below script was running fine until yesterday and now it will not work. What is wrong in the loop that tries to read the file and does the string replacement?

```
@echo off

:loop
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION EnableExtensions
SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`kubectl get ns`) DO (


echo %%F|find "che" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    set "jijijiji=ghghghg"
) else (
    FOR /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%G IN ("%%F") DO (

        echo %%G
        set "INTEXTFILE=secret.yaml"
        set "SEARCHTEXT=billy"
        del secret_%%G.yaml
        del this.yaml
        for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "%INTEXTFILE%"') do (
            set "string=%%A"
            set "modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%%G!"
            echo !modified!>>"secret_%%G.yaml"
        )
        copy "secret_%%G.yaml" "this.yaml"
        kubectl apply -f this.yaml
        del this.yaml

        )

    )
)
ENDLOCAL
timeout /t 10
goto loop
```

Comment: What does "will not work" mean?  Provide enough context to reproduce the issue and describe desired vs. current behavior.  Take out anything not required to reproduce the issue.  What is "kubectl"?  What does the YAML look like?

Comment: **This script has never worked properly!** Because `%INTEXTFILE%` should be `!INTEXTFILE!`, and `%SEARCHTEXT%`, should be `!SEARCHTEXT!`. However you cannot do `Set "modified=!string:!SEARCHTEXT!=%%G!"`, so you'd need to add another layer of expansion, _(or `call` another label with it as an argument)_.

Answer (score 1):

Like Compo said, that script can't work, because of the bugs.
When it ever worked, then by random!
Only when `INTEXTFILE` and  `SEARCHTEXT` are defined BEFORE the script starts, it could work.

But the fix is simple.
Move both SET statements before the first FOR-Loop

```
@echo off

:loop
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION EnableExtensions
SET count=1
set "INTEXTFILE=secret.yaml"
set "SEARCHTEXT=billy"
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`kubectl get ns`) DO (
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @compo @jeb. It helped me. I used powershell in the script:

```
@echo off

:loop
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION EnableExtensions
SET count=1
set "INTEXTFILE=secret.yaml"
set "SEARCHTEXT=billy"
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`kubectl get ns`) DO (


echo %%F|find "che" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    set "dummy=set"
) else (

    FOR /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%G IN ("%%F") DO (

        echo %%G
        powershell -Command "(gc secret.yaml) -replace '!SEARCHTEXT!', '%%G' | Out-File -encoding ASCII secret_%%G.yaml"
        copy "secret_%%G.yaml" "this.yaml"
        kubectl apply -f this.yaml
        del this.yaml

        )

    )
)
ENDLOCAL
timeout /t 100
goto loop
```